# GWT SimplePager - LastPageButton disabled?

Tags: gwt

In GWT when using SimplePager the LastPage button is disabled - but why?

See example in section: "Adding Paging Controls"
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html

If you copy the sample in and run it, you will see that the LastPageButton is disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the LastPageButton, but the FastForward Button, which is disabled because the constructor used to initialize the pager sets it to a value that it will be enabled if the remaining number of items is larger than 1000 (and the example contains only 200 items, just increase it to 2000 to see it).
There is a LastPageButton, but in the constructor used in the example disables it. You can enable the LastPageButton by using the following constructor to initialize the pager:

```
  public SimplePager(TextLocation location, Resources resources, boolean showFastForwardButton,
      final int fastForwardRows, boolean showLastPageButton)
```

Comment: Any idea how to do that through UiBinder? Or should I just use provided option?

Comment: Yes use the provided option. It's the most simple to use since the widget itself has no specific UiBinder constructor annotation that would make it possible to use set the parameters in the ui.xml.